# Image Upload in database using c# not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, image-uploading

[image: image of page unreachable]I using c#. I get the page unreachable error when saving to the official database.  Results is image. Why ?

```
  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=name;Initial Catalog=dbname;User ID=sa;Password=pss");
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
   {
       string strname = FileUpload1.FileName.ToString();
        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/upload/") + strname);
       con.Open();
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO image( imageurl)VALUES('" + strname + "')", con);
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       con.Close();
             }

            <div class="form-group">
           <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
     <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server"></asp:FileUpload>
    <asp:Button ID="Button3" class="btn btn-success" runat="server" 
    Text="Dosya Yükle" OnClick="Button3_Click"></asp:Button>
                [![enter image description here][1]][1] </div>
                  </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your application and determining the exception if there is any?

Comment: The size of image must be large. Try with small size image.

Answer (score 0):

For insert an Image to `database` you have to Save that byte on `database`.

But you saved that `urlImage` on `database`do you have a particular reason??

Example for save the byte:

```
Image img = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Lenna.jpg");
byte[] arr;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    arr =  ms.ToArray();
}
```

After that you have an array to save that in database.

Comment: Thank you. Please give me the example

Comment: @Engineer23 I have changed my answer. check that please.

Comment: @Engineer23 Do you check this?

Comment: @Engineer23 What is your mean about not working? didn't insert? or download?

Comment: @Engineer23 could you send your picture to my Email? amirkieper2@gmail.com